# Squid и запрет сайтов

Tags: squid

Наконец после долгих попыток у меня заработал Squid.

Теперь мне нужно закрыть списку ip адресов все сайты кроме сайтов белого списка, делаю так все работает сайты загружается только те которые в белом списке.

...................................................................................

```
acl all_sites dst 0.0.0.0/0acl sell_ips src "/etc/squid/sellroom/ip"acl sell_urls url_regex  "/etc/squid/sellroom/whitelist"http_access allow sell_ips sell_urlshttp_access deny sell_ips all_sites
```

...................................................................................

Трассировка с ПК находешегося за прокси сервером

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Администратор>tracert yandex.ruТрассировка маршрута к yandex.ru [213.180.193.11]с максимальным числом прыжков 30:  1    <1 мс    <1 мс    <1 мс  192.168.1.1  2     2 ms     1 ms     1 ms  drs8.oktgs.ufanet.ru [94.41.61.41]  3     2 ms     2 ms     2 ms  94.41.61.46.dynamic.ufanet.ru [94.41.61.46]  4     5 ms     5 ms     5 ms  92.50.191.118.static.ufanet.ru [92.50.191.118]  5    31 ms    31 ms    30 ms  193.106.112.112  6     *        *        *     Превышен интервал ожидания для запроса.  7    45 ms    45 ms    45 ms
```

С прокси сервера компьютер с адресом 192.168.0.2 пингуется, а с ПК за прокси нет.

Comment: А зачем RDP через squid???????

Answer (score 1):

squid это HTTP прокси, он умеет пробрасывать только http трафик. возможно он еще может работать как socks, тогда впринципе он сможет пробросить и другие виды трафика, но программы работающие через него должны поддерживать socks протокол.

А вот ping и tracert они вообще не проксируются, потому как используют протокол ICMP.
Если тебе надо что бы все прозрачно ходило, тебе нужен не прокси, а маскарад, т.е. NAT трафика.

Для linux например это делает iptables.
`iptables -I POSTROUTING -t nat -s 192.168.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE` обеспечит прозрачный выход для всех компов из подсети 192.168.0.0-192.168.0.255.

Answer (score 0):

Для этого на удалённом Вендовом сервере надо включить [RPC over HTTPS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-RU/library/windows/desktop/aa378642(v=vs.85).aspx).

Но с Пятаком согласен - это тонкое извращение!

Comment: Вот ещё в помощь: http://allcomputers.us/windows_server/windows-server-2008-r2---understanding-remote-desktop-services-(part-2)---rd-gateway---rd-web-access.aspx

Comment: Мне не нужно что бы RDP работал через SQUID, RDP не работает на компах на которых я заблочил все сайты ....

Comment: Сайты, и RDP разные вещи, если по проще, то браузеры пользователей вам надо настроить на squid а все остальное должно ходить без всяких прокси. А по факту, повесить squid на порт отличный от 80, например 8080, а на шлюзе сделать dnat с 80 на 8080 порт. И все браузеры у вас на squid и завернутся, причем прозрачно!!!

Comment: Так и есть все работает squid на 80 порте, но у тех у кого заблочены сайты ничего не работает кроме сайтов белого листа.

Comment: с клиентского компа     tracert yandex.ruчто говорит?

Comment: обновил вопрос